# Create multiple tabs from a dropdown with a template in the same sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a sheet with all the workout data from my weights class. I have about 200 students listed on the Player Database sheet.

On the 3-Day Tracking sheet, I would like to enter information for each student by choosing their name from the dropdown on that sheet.

I need to find a way to print each student's data. I would like to be able to create a tab for each student with all the data from the 3-Day Tracking sheet and then print each tab with the same format as the 3-Day Tracking tab.

Any help would be appreciated.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NhzYAyH5sEyC-sKITX7oNh099NjjyrngWbzo8MXCYy4/edit#gid=312809917

Comment: Your link is not public

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way to automate printing of a Spreadsheet.  You could have all sheets that you want to print go to a pdf and then you manually print that pdf.

Comment: @mimi I just made it public! Thank you.